# I want to be able to press a button and then make a different Frame visible and hide the one i was using

Tags: java

I have multiple JFrames that i want to be able to switch between with a button press.

Here is my code for my login Frame (without the auto generated code made by NetBeans)

```
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mzamomstha.registration;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Enzo
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    

    
    
    public LearnerDatabase learnerDatabaseFrame;
    
    public void setLearnerDatabase (LearnerDatabase learnerDatabaseFrame) {
        this.learnerDatabaseFrame = learnerDatabaseFrame;
    }
    
    public void openLearnerDataBase() {
        Login
        new LearnerDatabase().setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public TeacherDatabase teacherDatabase;
    
    public void setTeacherDatabase (TeacherDatabase teacherDatabase) {
        this.teacherDatabase = teacherDatabase;
    }
    
    public void openTeacherDatabase() {
        teacherDatabase.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public ParentDatabase parentDatabase;
    
    public void setParentDatabase (ParentDatabase parentDatabase) {
        this.parentDatabase = parentDatabase;
    }
    
    public void openParentDatabase() {
        parentDatabase.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    
    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        edtUsername = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        edtPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Login Frame");
        setName("loginFrame"); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("Username:");

        jLabel2.setText("Password:");

        btnLogin.setText("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                                .addComponent(edtPassword))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addGap(100, 100, 100)
                                .addComponent(edtUsername, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(130, 130, 130)
                        .addComponent(btnLogin)))
                .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(edtUsername, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(edtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(btnLogin)
                .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("loginFrame");

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        boolean parentLogin = false;
        boolean teacherLogin = false;
        boolean adminLogin = false;
        boolean learnerLogin = false;
        String username = edtUsername.getText();
        String password = edtPassword.getText();
        
        //Leaner Login Details
        if (username.equals("Enzo") && password.equals("EnzoPassword")) {
            learnerLogin = true;
        }
        //Parent Login Details
        if (username.equals("Sharon") && password.equals("SharonPassword")) {
            parentLogin = true;
        }
        //Teacher Login Details
        if (username.equals("Karl") && password.equals("KarlPassword")) {
            teacherLogin = true;
        }
        //Admin Login Details
        if (username.equals("Michael") && password.equals("MichaelPassword")) {
            adminLogin = true;
        }
        
        
        if (learnerLogin) {
            openLearnerDataBase();
        }
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        
        
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLogin;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField edtPassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField edtUsername;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

When i press btnLogin i want to be able to display either my LearnerDataBase, TeacherDataBase or ParentDatabase (those are the names of the Frames, i named them like that because there are tables on it that will display my databases) depending on the username and password they enter. And of course the "details" of the learner, teacher and parent is going to be changed to fit with a database, its just to test.

If needed i can also add my other frames code.

With that code i have there i get a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" Error.

This is my stack trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mzamomstha.registration.Login.openLearnerDataBase(Login.java:21)
at mzamomstha.registration.Login.btnLoginActionPerformed(Login.java:151)
at mzamomstha.registration.Login.access$000(Login.java:12)
at mzamomstha.registration.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

Also this I am just learning so I don't know all the fancy techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you dispose of the current frame if you don't need it  and then open the frame you need like this : (this is the case where LearnerDatabase class deosn't have a Jframe.

```
public void openLearnerDataBase() {
    this.dispose();
    new LearnerDatabase().setVisible(true);
}
```

in case LearnerDatatabase has a Jframe like this : `JFrame learnerDatabaseFrame = new JFrame();`, at the end of your `initComponents()` function add  `learnerDatabaseFrame.setVisible(true);` and add change the function `openLearnerDataBase()` to :

```
public void openLearnerDataBase() {
    this.dispose();
    new LearnerDatabase();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was able to open the new frame, but i cant close the Login Frame. When i created the frame i called it Login (the file is named Login.java). I then went to the design view and changed the properties. I made the name loginFrame and the accessible name loginFrame, although when i go to source i can only select the class Login and then there is no option for dispose or to setVisisble. AKA i cant type Login.dispose(); or Login.setVisible(false);

Comment: @ZaEnzoZa I am not talking about the java class I am talking about the frame that you createdthe variable like `Frame = new JFrame();`  in your Java class named `Login`. no need to edit your java classes names just find the variable you used. If you still can't find it can you please show the code of your Login class

Comment: @Annas ABEA i just updated my post and it has all my Login frame's code

Comment: @ZaEnzoZa Hope this code works. I have tried it and it did work for me

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to only have one `JFrame` in a *Swing* application. Therefore, I suggest that rather than having a separate `JFrame` for each "database", have a separate `JPanel`. Use [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and place each "database" on it.

Create a [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) as your login window and display it when your application starts up. Once the user logs in display the relevant database according to the supplied login name.

1. Create a separate `JPanel` for each "database".
   Admin database

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AdminDb extends JPanel {
    public AdminDb() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        add(new JLabel("Admin Database"));
    }
}
```

Teacher database

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TeacherDb extends JPanel {
    public TeacherDb() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        add(new JLabel("Teacher Database"));
    }
}
```

etc.

When you start up your application, you don't yet know which database to display, so I created a "blank" database.

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UnknownDb extends JPanel {
    public UnknownDb() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }
}
```

2. Here is the login dialog class.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class LoginDlg extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JPasswordField  edtPassword;
    private JTextField  edtUsername;

    public LoginDlg(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, "Login", true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add(createLoginPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        dispose();
    }

    public String getEdtUsername() {
        return edtUsername.getText();
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Login");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(button);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createLoginPanel() {
        JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 5;
        gbc.insets.left = 20;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 20;
        JLabel usrLabel = new JLabel("User");
        loginPanel.add(usrLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 20;
        edtUsername = new JTextField(15);
        loginPanel.add(edtUsername, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 20;
        gbc.insets.left = 20;
        gbc.insets.right = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;
        JLabel pwLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        loginPanel.add(pwLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.right = 20;
        edtPassword = new JPasswordField(15);
        loginPanel.add(edtPassword, gbc);
        return loginPanel;
    }
}
```

3. Finally, the application class, containing a `main()` method and displaying the single `JFrame` of the application.

```java
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DataBase implements Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  databasesPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createDatabasesPanel() {
        databasesPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        databasesPanel.add(new UnknownDb(), "unknown");
        databasesPanel.add(new AdminDb(), "admin");
        databasesPanel.add(new LearnerDb(), "learner");
        databasesPanel.add(new ParentDb(), "parent");
        databasesPanel.add(new TeacherDb(), "teacher");
        return databasesPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Database");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createDatabasesPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        LoginDlg loginDlg = new LoginDlg(frame);
        String cardName;
        switch (loginDlg.getEdtUsername()) {
            case "Michael":
                cardName = "admin";
                break;
            case "Enzo":
                cardName = "learner";
                break;
            case "Sharon":
                cardName = "parent";
                break;
            case "Karl":
                cardName = "teacher";
                break;
            default:
                cardName = "unknown";
        }
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) databasesPanel.getLayout();
        layout.show(databasesPanel, cardName);
    }

    /**
     * Start here!
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new DataBase());
    }
}
```

This is a screen capture when the application starts up.

[image: login]

Now let's say the user enters the login *Karl* and presses the *Login* button. Here is a screen capture of the application after pressing the login button.

[image: after login]

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will do this next time but i don't really have time to do it over now

Comment: so i am now making a new program and i want to do what you showed. Dis you make a new JFrame or use a normal Java class?